# putty + xargs + vim = no newline in putty

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I typed this command in putty, where thereis only one file, filename:
find . -name filename | xargs vim

after I close vim, I cannot get a new line in putty, unless I press Ctrl+C
user@ubuntu:~$ user@ubuntu:~$ user@ubuntu:~$

how can I fix this (other than opening a new shell in putty) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal emulation has been corrupted. I have found that I can fix this by blindly typing `reset<ENTER>`

Answer (score 2):

Using find, xargs and vim in that combination makes a horrible mess of your terminal.

If you want to use the output of find for vim, the following works:

```
find . -name filename -exec vim {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really pipe into vim, interactive programs really need to be controlled by a tty, not a pipe.

Try "Ctrl+J stty sane Ctrl+J". This will setup your terminal with a default set of settings, which are usually close to what you want. You have to press Ctrl-J to get a newline, because the mode which translates enter to the end of line has been turned off.

Comment: He isn't - he's piping to `xargs`.

Comment: And then vim is then going to inherit the pipe as stdin. If you run the command you'll find that you get the error 

Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal